# What does `invalid initialization of non-const reference` mean?

Tags: c++, templates

When compiling this code I get the following [error](http://codepad.org/ZWzFIYzY):

> In function 'int main()':
>   Line 11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Main&' from a temporary of type 'Main'

Here's my code:

```
template <class T>
struct Main
{
    static Main tempFunction(){
       return Main();
    }
};

int main()
{
   Main<int> &mainReference = Main<int>::tempFunction(); // <- line 11
}
```

I don't understand why? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Please post the exact error messages from the compiler.

Comment: Your template declaration doesn't depend on the parameterized class.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Yes but error is not because of that.

Comment: "gives some error"?  You win the MOST vague statement award!  What error? What line?  What compiler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ temporaries cannot be bound to non-constant references.

`Main<int> &mainReference = Main<int>::tempFunction();`

Here you are trying to assign the result of an rvalue expression to a non-constant reference `mainReference` which is invalid.

Try making it `const`

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: Generally this doesn't result in a compiler *error* though.  Usually you get a warning.

Comment: @Noah Roberts :No, the program is ill-formed. MSVC++ supports this as a non-standard extension and compiles the code.

Comment: @Prasoon The article completes your answer.